# How to stop Cisco Services Application objects from stacking

Tags: c#, xml, http, cisco

I am working with Cisco phones and i want to send them alert messages.

I do this by posting the following to the phone

```
"<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL=\"Play:chime.raw\"/><ExecuteItem Priority=\"0\" URL=MY GET MESSAGE URL></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>";
```

My HTTP server then responds with a CiscoIPPhoneText xml object.

This is all working fine, however it is my desire not to have the messages stacking up on top of each other so that the user does not have to dismiss each message individually. I wish only for the most recent message to remain active on the phone so regardless of how many messages the phone has received the user can dismiss one and be returned home.

At first i included an `init:services` uri in the post but this caused a conflict with another service and my CiscoIPPhoneText was being dismissed immediately by the other service (i have no control over the other service).

Is there a way to return the phone to the home screen before an CiscoIPPhoneText is displayed or any other way to ensure that only one message is active?

Thanks

Comment: I have been all through http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/all_models/xsi/3_3_2/english/programming/guide/ipphs332.html
and was unable to find anything useful

Comment: Interesting.  If they don't have any sort of update/replace/delete methods for interacting with previous CiscoIPPhoneExecute calls to the phone still existing in some internal queue within the device, I'd say contact Cisco support to request this feature.

Comment: I can reinitialize the services to remove everything from this "queue" but the problem with that is another service i can't control seems to be dismissing my messages. Do you know if there are default services that start anytime the services do?

Comment: No, sorry Paperwaste.  I don't have much experience in this topic though I am interested in it.  By the fact that remote services can actually force dismiss other messages from any other remote service, it seems this feature... has issues.

Comment: Its not a very tidy API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

`App:Close:0` is an internal URI which closes the current (or specified) application.

All my messages have the same AppId so when this URI is invoked all my messages close